# View controller containment Z position

Tags: ios, view, controller, containment

I have the following issue: 
I create a view controller and I add a child view controller inside it. 
The child view controller view is inserted below an existing subview (button A) of the parent view controller. 
When I try to transition to a new child view controller, its view is not added anymore below button A, but above it.

Is there a way to keep the Z position of the child view?

Answer (score 1):

After adding the new view controller, call:

```
[parentView bringSubviewToFront:theButton];
```

Alternatively, use `insertSubview:belowSubview:` to insert the new view controller, specifying the button for the `belowSubview:` argument.

Comment: The first solution works but it is somehow a hack. For example, if I have multiple buttons, I have to bring them all to front.IMHO, the second solution is not good practice, because for VCs transitioning, the views should not be manipulated directly. What I am trying to do is to find a more standard way to keep the view of the newly added VC in the same Z position of the old VC.